# Modify Monitor Color Profiles / Settings

Tags: 10.10, laptop, intel-graphics, monitor

I can't seem to find this anywhere but every other OS has this...

How can I just modify the color settings on my monitor, e.g. white balance, gamma, etc?

Also, just in case, i'm on a Lenovo ThinkPad.

Here is my graphics card specs:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
```

Comment: Knowing the graphics-chip in there would help us a lot...

Comment: whats the command to get that info? I'll google it too...

Comment: @Oscar Godson: `lspci | grep "VGA"` should output your graphics-chip. If it does output nothing, please add the complete output of `lspci` to your question.

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)

Comment: @Oscar Godson: Please add this to your question. You might also want to remove the colors tag and replace it with an intel one (I'd do it...but I don't have even closely enough rep :( ).

Answer (score 2):

[GNOME Color Manager](http://projects.gnome.org/gnome-color-manager/) can help with device profiles. Install the `gnome-color-manager` package and go to System > Preferences > Color Profiles.

Comment: how do I adjust it after? I have it installed but i can only see how to import things...

Comment: You need to install a color profile for your monitor first; if it's detected as "Unknown Monitor", settings will not be available. See http://yfrog.com/51gcmadjustp.

Comment: Is there a way to make it supported by some sort of plugin or driver?

Comment: @op did you figure this out? It seems there are no "settings" after the fact. I'm able to install an `.icc` profile that I made using Windows's simple GUI but it's pretty useless now unless I can adjust it.