# Color settings missing from Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, colors

After installing Ubuntu 22.04 the colours on the laptop's monitor don't look right (they are pinkish compared to the external monitor).

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1405938/198163) you need to change the colour profiles.
Going into my settings, there is nowhere to change colour profiles. According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/8759/198163) you have to install `GNOME Color Manager` which I did, but still no colour options in settings.

My GNOME version is version 42.0, and this is how my settings screen look like:

[Settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNZk2.png)

Comment: For me in 22.04 it's in settings as `Device Colour Profiles` immediately below `Removable Media`. Not where you may think it should be e.g. `Appearance` or `Screen Display`. I had to disable monitor colour profiles in 22.04 where my monitor was o.k. but changing display to a Samsung TV made the colours terrible.

Comment: You're right! Thanks, I also managed to miss it when searching for color instead of colour so doubly stupid but yeah, not where you's expect it to be

Comment: that should be in the main answer. Typing "color" as per the accepted answer does not work. @iasonas

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Settings
2. Type "Color" in search
3. Select "Color" tab
4. Press right arrow in box with your monitor name.
5. Select current color profile under line with monitor name
6. Choose Remove profile
7. Select line with your monitor name
8. Choose Add profile
9. Select Colorspace:sRGB, press ADD
   Viola! :)

Comment: This does nothing for me in Ubuntu 22. I can select a color profile for my monitor, I can select other color profiles, enable / disable it, and the color displays the same way (washed out, as if color management were turned off). It worked for me in Ubuntu 18 and when I upgraded it just stopped working even though the profile is the same and there are no error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where things just looked kind of pinkish and I thought it was an intentional style choice by Ubuntu for a little while. But then I noticed that cells in a spreadsheet I had highlighted blue actually showed pink on my laptop, but blue on an attached monitor and realized it was way off.

I went to Settings...Color and selected "Laptop Screen". That expanded "Automatic - XPS 15 9560", the only option for me. I clicked "Add profile" and tried out a few. The best for me was "Standard Space - Compatible with Adobe RGB (1998)", although it makes my whites a little bluish. At least I can tell the difference now between pink and blue highlights. Try out several options and see if you can find one you like.

If none of them work well, or if your color needs are more discriminating than mine, you may need to spend more time with calibration software like [DisplayCal](https://displaycal.net/) or hardware to dial it in. Then you can use the same interface to "Add profile"..."Import file" with a custom profile.

Answer (score 0):

In wayland, ability to change color from Settings is not there.

To do so use commandline:

```
colormgr get-profiles

colormgr get-devices
```

Then use this data in here:

```
colormgr device-add-profile Device_ID Profile_ID
```

The device ID is obtained from the output of "colormgr get-devices" and the profile ID from "colormgr get-profiles"

Like stated in [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ICC_profiles#Wayland)